# php ajax connection failure

Tags: php, ajax

Using the following I have tried a hundred different ways and all I get is the failure alert
Please could anyone spot my silly beginners mistake

myy.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect('adress','dbase','pass','table');
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT mycoat FROM $table");          
$response  = array();
while($array = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $response[] = $array;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

JavaScript:

```
function myfunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myy.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your url is correct? It should be starting with http(s):// or a slash / for relative urls.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should set the Content-Type properly.  Before you `echo` the JSON, add this line: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: change your error function to: error: function(response) { alert(response); } so we can have a better idea of what is failing.

Comment: Thanks kali, at last a little headway, following your advice the responce returns object Object, I just need to figur this error now

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed db connection link in `mysqli_query`

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT mycoat FROM $table");
```

instead of,

```
 $result = mysqli_query("SELECT mycoat FROM $table");
```